# Scala: DataFrame.join still creating duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two scala dataframes. Despite following the example given [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html) , I still get duplicates

```
  +----+----+----+-------+
  |  b1|  b2|  b3|$$RowId|
  +----+----+----+-------+
  |a1-1|a2-1|a3-1|      1|
  |a1-2|a2-2|a3-2|      2|
  |a1-3|a2-3|a3-3|      3|
  |null|null|null|      8|
  |null|null|null|      9|
  |null|null|null|     10|
  +----+----+----+-------+

  +-------+-----+-----+-----+
  |$$RowId|   b1|   b2|   b3|
  +-------+-----+-----+-----+
  |      1| null| null| null|
  |      2| null| null| null|
  |      3| null| null| null|
  |      8| b1-8| b2-8|b3-15|
  |      9| b1-9| b2-9|b3-17|
  |     10|b1-10|b2-10|b3-19|
  +-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to combine the data into one dataframe. I use join as follows:

```
val finalDF = colsToShiftRenamedDF.join(colsToKeepDF, Seq("$$RowId"))
```

The result is the following dataframe

```
  +-------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
  |$$RowId|  b1|  b2|  b3|   b1|   b2|   b3|
  +-------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
  |      1|a1-1|a2-1|a3-1| null| null| null|
  |      2|a1-2|a2-2|a3-2| null| null| null|
  |      3|a1-3|a2-3|a3-3| null| null| null|
  |      8|null|null|null| b1-8| b2-8|b3-15|
  |      9|null|null|null| b1-9| b2-9|b3-17|
  |     10|null|null|null|b1-10|b2-10|b3-19|
  +-------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are joining would definitely give you `columns` of each `table` even though they are `null`. **You should add some additional steps if you don't require the duplicates.**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = colsToShiftRenamedDF.as("t1").join(colsToKeepDF.as("t2"), Seq("$$RowId"))
  .select(col("$$RowId"),
    when(col("t1.b1").isNull || col("t1.b1") === "null", col("t2.b1")).otherwise(col("t1.b1")).as("b1"),
    when(col("t1.b2").isNull || col("t1.b2") === "null", col("t2.b2")).otherwise(col("t1.b2")).as("b2"),
    when(col("t1.b3").isNull || col("t1.b3") === "null", col("t2.b3")).otherwise(col("t1.b3")).as("b3"))
```

which will give you output `dataframe` as

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|$$RowId|b1   |b2   |b3   |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|1      |a1-1 |a2-1 |a3-1 |
|2      |a1-2 |a2-2 |a3-2 |
|3      |a1-3 |a2-3 |a3-3 |
|8      |b1-8 |b2-8 |b3-15|
|9      |b1-9 |b2-9 |b3-17|
|10     |b1-10|b2-10|b3-19|
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I came up with something similar in the end, but rather than using join, I used withColumn, which I suspect is slower as the process goes one column at a time. Thanks a million!!

Comment: My pleasure @Jake, thanks for the acceptance and upvote. :)

Comment: Ramesh, only if you can spare the time, is it possible to make the code dynamic depencing on the number of columns to be shift, say b1-bn and a1-an (where count bn==count an)? If yes, perhaps post as an additional answer. I know this is asking a lot, so please ignore if you are busy. I am already grateful for your help

Comment: I guess thats possible. why don't you ask another question if thats not been asked before. somebody else will answer if not me. :)

Comment: OK, I can ask as a separate question